# jquery if input contains phrase from array-child friendly global chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter, filtering

I have found some code for a chat system. I am going to be using it as a child-friendly (so I can't be blamed for anything) global chat. The way the code works is by checking the input to see if it contains any word from an array, if it does then the program will display something to a `<ol>` tag, for me to see if it works. Otherwise is does nothing.

**JQUERY**

```
var banned_words = {
    'songs': ['hello', 'sorry', 'blame'],
    'music': ['tempo', 'blues', 'rhythm']
};

function contains(words) {
    return function(word) {
        return (words.indexOf(word) > -1);
    };
};

function getTags(input, banned_words) {
    var words = input.match(/\w+/g);
    return Object.keys(banned_words).reduce(function(tags, classification) {
              var keywords = banned_words[classification];
              if (words.some(contains(keywords)))
                  tags.push(classification);
              return tags;
          }, []);
};


 // watch textarea for release of key press
 $('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {   
        $('#tags').empty();
        var tags = getTags($(this).val().toLowerCase(), banned_words);
        var children = tags.forEach(function(tag) {
            $('#tags').append($('<li>').text(tag));
        }); 
      if (e.keyCode == 13) { 

          var text = $(this).val();
          var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
          var length = text.length; 

          // send 
          if (length <= maxLength + 1) { 
              chat.send(text, name);    
              $(this).val("");

          } else {

              $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));

        }   


      }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
    <form id="send-message-area">
        <p style="text-align:center">Your message: </p>
        <input id="sendie" maxlength = '100' />
    </form>
    <ol id="tags">
    </ol>
```

But, what I'm also wanting to do is check if the input value contains phrases from the array so I can ban phrases that are too sensitive for children. How can I add this in, or is there another more efficient way to check the input?

**UPDATE**

I have already tried to place the phrase directly into the banned_words (I changed them as this post would get flagged for inappropriate language) and using the hexadecimal character for the space-bar. None of these worked.

Comment: I hope that's not what you really intend to filter....

Comment: So what is the problem? because it's working, is finding the words and it puts them in ol tag

Comment: No, I just had to put in some other words as this post would've flagged up for inappropriate language. And did you not read the post @nicholas ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try either of the following since the space is also a known charachter:

test 1:
Just put your phrase between quotes such as 'cry baby','red apple' etc.

sometimes it does not work, you can try

test 2:
replace the space with the hexidecimal character \x20 such as 'cry\x20baby','red\x20apple'

I hope one or both of these works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately they both don't work, I thought the '\x20' would but the code specifically compares the last word typed. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done some more research and have found a cool plugin for JQuery. It's called jQuery.profanityFilter. It uses a `json` file filled with sensative words.
Link to github download: https://github.com/ChaseFlorell/jQuery.ProfanityFilter